# How can I select the last 5 characters?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I trying to select last 5 symbols from each row and I use the following code...

```
public void autoComplete() {

    database = new Database(this) ;
    databaseSQL = database.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor numbersCursor = databaseSQL.rawQuery("SELECT RIGHT(number, 5) FROM Cars", null);
    number = new String[numbersCursor.getCount()];
    int j = 0;
    while (numbersCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String str_number = numbersCursor.getString(numbersCursor.getColumnIndex("number"));
        number[j] = str_number;
        j++;
    } numbersCursor.close();
```

...but "RIGHT" in the query is underlined

Comment: What do you mean by "underlined"?

Comment: Do you mean you have more than 5 columns and you want to return or select only the last 5 column values of each row?

Comment: <result column>, ALL or DISTINCT expected, got 'RIGHT'

Comment: NO, I have TABLE 'cars' with 3 columns (id, number, model) in it, and I want to select last 5 SYMBOLS from each ROW in 'number' COLUMN

Comment: select substr(number, -5) .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **SQLite** there is no `RIGHT()` function. 
You must use [`SUBSTR()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(number, LENGTH(number) - 4) FROM Cars
```

Comment: `SUBSTR (number, 2, 3)` returns the 2nd, 3d and 4th chars of the string, not the last 5.

Comment: sorry my mistake "SELECT SUBSTR (number, -4) AS number FROM Cars" and it works!

Comment: For 5 chars it should be `substr(number, -5)` if you want a negative argument.